# sdl2-config: command not found. fatal error: file not found

Tags: c, config, sdl, sdl-2, fatal-error

I have correctly installed sdl2 and used xcode to make a new command line tool to run sdl2. However whenever I run my makefile I am getting a fatal error.

My '.h' file has `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` in it and this is my makefile:

```
CXX = gcc
NAME = Tiger

# Warnings frequently signal eventual errors:
CXXFLAGS=`sdl2-config --cflags` -g -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -I `sdl2-config --prefix`/include/

LDFLAGS = `sdl2-config --libs` -lm

OBJS = $(NAME).o

Tiger: $(OBJS) libezdraw.a
    $(CXX) -o $(NAME) $(NAME).o $(CXXFLAGS) -L. -lezdraw $(LDFLAGS)

$(NAME).o: $(NAME).c ezdraw.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *~
    rm -f $(NAME)
```

Does anyone know what I’m missing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depends on which platform you are on and how you installed SDL2.

You could try `pkg-config --cflags sdl2` and `pkg-config --libs sdl2`.

This utility can discover the right flags for you: https://github.com/xyproto/cxx

Comment: So it would look like this? ```CXXFLAGS=`sdl2-config --cflags sdl2` -g -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -I `sdl2-config --prefix`/include/

LDFLAGS = `sdl2-config --libs sdl2` -lm```

Comment: No. Not like that.